# Which is better?

Tags: jsp, jstl

which one of the following is better?

```
<c:set var="var1" value="false" scope="request"/>
<c:if test="${someCondition}">
    <c:set var="var1" value="true" scope="request"/>
</c:if>
```

Or the following

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${someCondition}">
        <c:set var="var1" value="true" scope="request"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="var1" value="false" scope="request"/>
    <c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither, this looks best for me:

```
<c:set var="var1" value="${someCondition}" scope="request"/>
```

Comment: I agree this is easier if the value to be set is a Boolean. But I used boolean as an example here. what if we are setting non-boolean values?

Comment: Use what you find the clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The first, because it is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do what Tomasz suggested. If you have different values rather than booleans, you can use a ternary statement:

```
<c:set var="var1" value="${someCondition == 'someValue' ? 'valueA' : 'valueB'}" scope="request"/>
```